# Trace facebook user ip. Is it even possible?

Tags: facebook, ip, user-tracking

As I know facebook chat is working like `user <> server <> user` and it's not P2P. I was talking with some guys today and they were pretty sure it's possible to `netstat` a facebook user IP address. I'm not familiar how FB chat works, but I highly doubt they're using P2P in their chat. So my question is it possible to `netstat` a facebook IP, or any way to find his IP without sending a link or using any phishing tools?

Most of the articles in the google results, says this is actually possible: [here](https://www.google.bg/search?q=facebook%20stack&oq=facebook%20stack&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i65j69i60l2j0.2038j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=get%20ip%20of%20facebook%20user&safe=off&start=10).

Comment: As others have said it doesn't seem that chat is P2P. But Facebook does support video chat (although I've never used it), it's possible that it could be P2P.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook chat is running on [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) protocol. It is decentralised, but not P2P. It is similar to email - there is no central server, but lots of domain servers talking to each other and taking care of their clients. I doubt that it would be possible to get IP address from XMPP.

Answer (score 11):

Directly, no.

Indirectly, it's possible. One way:

1. Have a web server, whose access log you control, up and running.
2. Send your chat partner a unique hyperlink pointing to that web server, have them click the link. For example: http://yourdomain.com/JohnDoe.html (the web page does not have to exist, throwing a 404 is fine).
3. Check your web server's access log to get the IP address of requests to /JohnDoe.html.
4. You have your conversation partner's IP address.

Comment: A dirty trick always valid. But this is a kamikaze... you also disclose your identity at that website owner

Answer (score 7):

Facebook's chat platform utilises the XMPP protocol, which does not disclose the IP address of the client.

You are correct in saying that Facebook does not use P2P in their chat. As far as I know, it is **not possible** to get a facebook IP via web chat of a contact without using social engineering.

It may be worth checking whether IP addresses are disclosed when using Facebook's custom chat client, however, it is unlikely that client IP addresses are ever disclosed.

Comment: and what about Calls on Facebook Messenger ? It should be the same. Both output connection must be binded somewhere ?